# Connection error at the db creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails project, that works with postgresql and pg.
I installed postgres in my computer, but when I try to create/migrate the db of the aplication, I get the following error:

> ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I created already the user for the application.
I didn't have the postgresql folder at least, I had to create it.
What could be the problem?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It sounds like you don't have PostgreSQL running.  Have you started Postgres server?

Comment: Yes I did. I think it's a socket problem

Answer (score 0):

By default the socket connection file is located in the /tmp folder, you can find it in /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432. To change the location check ~/.parts/var/postgresql/postgresql.conf file, but /var/run directory is not writable now, you can't select /var/run as the socket file location.